# Changing color of molecules using cmd

Tags: python, pymol

I have written a python script to draw molecules in PyMol utilizing PYMOL API. I had loaded a file with geometry and then I wanted to change a color of carbon atoms. 
I utilized `cmd.color( "black", selection = "*C" )`, but any changes were displayed. I am not sure if I understand all arguments of the color function. Maybe something wrong is with the second argument?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have correct atoms selected in "*C" variable?

```
cmd.color('black', selection=cmd.select('c*'))
```

https://pymol.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=api:cmd:select

since "c*" selects every all carbon atoms such as ca, cb, and so on, this solution might work.

Comment: I have not. I was looking for a specific function to select atoms, but I only found cmd.select("%s_%s"%(prefix,stretch), "none") and coudn't understand arguments.

Comment: Did my solution worked for you? if so, would you accept my solution. or you can do this job in two lines. first line selects the atoms and puts in a group. Second you can color the group.